# How do you get the inputted file name in savefiledialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

If I were to enter a name for my file to save in the savefile dialog, how do I programmatically get the name I inputted? 
If I do saveFileDialog.fileName i'll get the full name. Say I entered "myfile" and it was saved in the folder "mynotepad".
 I want to get that "myfile" not "c:\programfiles\documents\mynotepad\myfile.txt".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, If you do know how to get `c:\programfiles\documents\mynotepad\myfile.txt` (and it appears like you do) than you can use the `System.IO.Path` class to get the filename

```
using System.IO; 

...

    string fn = Path.GetFileName(@"c:\programfiles\documents\mynotepad\myfile.txt");
```

if you don't want the `.txt` than use `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`

```
string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"c:\programfiles\documents\mynotepad\myfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Path.GetFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(saveFileDialog.FileName);
```

Comment: Thanks although it still gives me the file type at the end. Although I fixed that by splitting it. This is how my code looks now:        ` file = new FileInfo(saveDialog.FileName);
                //Set title of form equal to saved file name
                string theName = Path.GetFileName(file.FullName);
                string[] split = theName.Split('.');
                this.Text = split[0];`

Comment: As @Sam I Am pointed out, you can use Path.GetFileNameWIthoutExtension() instead of splitting.